# Two doubts in the paper of Brezis Merle in blow up analysis of the equation $-\Delta u=Ve^u$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

1. I was going through the paper of Brezis and Merle [1]. In theorem 3 step 2 it's written that the boundedness of  $f_n=V_ne^{u_n}$ in $L_{loc}^p(\Omega)$ implies $\mu\in L^1(\Omega)\cap L_{loc}^p(\Omega)$. Let $v_n$ be a solution of $-\Delta v_n=f_n$ in $\Omega$ and $v_n=0$ in $\partial\Omega$. Then $v_n\to v$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$ where $v$ is solution of $-\Delta v=\mu$ in $\Omega$ and $v=0$ in $\partial\Omega$. I am not getting how this conclusion follows i.e. why this implies the uniform convergence of $v_n\to v$ on compact subsets of $\Omega $.

2. At the very beginning they prove a basic inequality which they use later. In the last line of the proof they mention that for $y\in B_R$ we have
   $$\DeclareMathOperator{\dmu}{d\!}
   \int\limits_{B_R}\left(\frac{2R}{|x-y|}\right)^{2-\frac{\delta}{2\pi}} \dmu x\leq\int_{B_R}\left(\frac{2R}{|x|}\right)^{2-\frac{\delta}{2\pi}}\dmu x.
   $$
   Does this result follows from translation? Otherwise $|x-y|\ngeq |x|$ in general. And also why
   $$\DeclareMathOperator{\diam}{diam}
   \int\limits_{B_R}\left(\frac{2R}{|x|}\right)^{2-\frac{\delta}{2\pi}}\dmu x=\frac{4\pi^2}{\delta}\big(\diam(\Omega)\big)^2\;?
   $$
   Also this is not coming from radial integration as one term $2^{2-\frac{\delta}{2\pi}}$ survives.

Any idea would be very much helpful.

**Reference**

[1] Haïm Brézis, Frank Merle, "Uniform estimates and blow-up behavior for solutions of $−Δu=V(x)e^u$
in two dimensions" Communications in Partial Differential Equations 16, No. 8-9, 1223-1253 (1991), [MR1132783](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1132783), [Zbl 0746.35006](https://zbmath.org/0746.35006).

Comment: Concerning 2., they use the fact that the integral of a radial decreasing function on a set $\Omega$ is maximized when $\Omega$ is a ball centered at 0 having the same volume. However, in the computation for $B_R$ I also find a different constant.

Comment: For 1., a possibility is the following. Having  $\|f_n\|_1 \leq C$ first infer that $\|v_n\|_1 \leq C_1$ and also $\|v_n\|_{1,q} \leq C_2$ if $q<n/(n-1)=2$. These estimates are not obvious but well-known. Then use interior estimates for the Laplacian (since $f_n$ are bounded in $L^p_{loc}$) to deduce compactness, hence convergence, in $W^{2,p}_{loc}$. Since $p>n/2=1$ you have uniform convergence, by Sobolev embedding.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I see how these estimates imply the result however can you give a reference for these? I believe $ \|v_{n}\|_{1} \leq C$ follows from Green's identity but I can't quite see how to prove the $ W^{1,q} $ bound you state.

Comment: I admit that everything is vague. Concerning the $L^1$ estimate it follows from the Green function (or either if $u-\Delta u=f$ by integrating by parts against smooth aprroximation of the signum of $u$). Since elliptic regularity does not hold in $L^1$ one cannot get $W^{2,1}$ estimates. However the estimate for gradient is true (if needed) or also, having $f_n \in L^p$ one can use interior $W^{2,p}$ estimates to get bounds for the secpond derivatives.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Yea I certainly agree with the $L^1$ estimate you stated. In my proof I need the $ \|v_{n}\|_{1,q}  \leq C $ bound you stated. Do you have a reference for this particular estimate?

Comment: I have notes in Italian by L. Boccardo, dealing with elliptic equations with data in $L^1$ or even measures and these estimates are there (they go back to Stampacchia). With these names, I hope, you should find appropriate references; if not I can try again. There is also a parabolic approach: in the whole space solve $u_t-\Delta u=f$ through the heat kernel and write the solution of $\lambda v-\Delta v=f$ as the laplace transform of the semigroup. Then you differentiate under the integral and the $L^q$ norm of the gradient is finite exactly for $q<N/(N-1)$.

Comment: Then you can localize or perturb these estimates. (I wrote this in an old papewr with A. Lunardi, in a more general setting)

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Ok thank you very much for these references! Yeah it was a little difficult for me to find resources doing L^p theory when p=1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\norm[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}$
I realize this is a bit late but I'd like to elaborate on Professor Metafune's very interesting and helpful comments. I'll prove how your claim 1. follows from the following:

**Lemma 1**
Let $\Omega$ be a $C^{1,1}$ bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d \geq 2$. Suppose $f \in L^1(\Omega)$ and $ u \in W_{0}^{1,1}(\Omega)$ is a weak solution to the equation $$ -\Delta u = f .$$ Then if $ 1\leq q < \frac{d}{d-1} $there is a constant $C=C(q,d)$ such that $$ \norm u_{W_{0}^{1,q}} \leq C \norm f_{L^1}.$$

Then I'll provide a proof of this Lemma that I found in Prof. Luigi Orsina's notes [Elliptic equations
with measure data]

[1]: [https://www.ugr.es/~edp/Talks/Luigi-Abril_2009/Curso.pdf](https://www.ugr.es/%7Eedp/Talks/Luigi-Abril_2009/Curso.pdf). I'm not sure who the proof is originally due to but I suspect it is Stampacchia.

**Proof of 1.**

Set $ w_{n} = v_{n} -v $, so that by Lemma 1, for all $ 1< q < 2$, we have $$ \|w_{n}\|_{W^{1,q}(\Omega)} \leq C=C(q) .$$ Now by the Sobolev embedding theorem, $$ \|w_{n}\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq C=C(p) .$$ Indeed, if $p >2$ this follows directly from above, and otherwise it follows directly from above and Hölder's inequality. Fix a compact subset $ K$ of $\Omega$. By the Calderón–Zygmund estimate, combined with the above, $$ \|w_{n}\|_{W^{2,p}(K)} $$  $$\leq C  (\| \Delta w_{n} \|_{L^p(K)} + \|w_{n}\|_{L^p(\Omega)}) \leq C=C(K,p),$$ since $f_{n}$ are uniformly bounded in $L^p_{loc}.$ By the Sobolev embedding again , there exists $\alpha > 0 $ such that $$\|w_{n}\|_{C^{0,\alpha}(K)} \leq C .$$ Thus by Arzela-Ascoli, $w_{n}$ must converge uniformly on $K$ after passing to a subsequence. The uniform limit must be $0$ by the weak convergence to $0$. This proves 1.

**Now here is the proof of Lemma 1**

We denote various function spaces without the domain $\Omega$, as $\Omega$  is understood to be the domain of all functions defined here. Roughly speaking, we truncate $f$, work with solutions to the Poisson equation with this truncated $f$, and estimate the measures of level sets using the Layer-Cake formula. Define $f_{n} = f1_{\{|f|<n\}}$, so that clearly $f_{n} \in L^{\infty} $, $ \|f_{n}\|_{L^1} \leq \|f\|_{L^1} $ and $ f_{n} \to f $ in $L^1.$ Consider $u_{n}$ to be the $H_{0}^1$ solution to $$ (1) \hspace{1 cm} -\Delta u_{n} = f_{n}. $$Define $$u_{n}^k = u_{n}1_{\{|u_{n}| <k \}} + k1_{\{|u_{n} \geq  k\}}.$$ Then $u_{n}^k$ is a valid test function to test equation (1) against. Since $\nabla u_{n} = \nabla u_{n}^k$ on the support of $ \nabla u_{n}^k, $ we get $$(2) \hspace{1 cm} \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u_{n}^k|^2 \leq \int_{\Omega} f_{n}u_{n}^{k}\leq k\|f\|_{L^1}. $$ Denote by $2^* $ the Sobolev conjugate to $2$, if $d \geq 3.$ If $ d = 2, $ we simply work with some $p >2$ in what follows and the argument does not change substantially. By Sobolev's inequality and (2) , $$\bigg(\int_{\Omega} (u_{n}^k)^{2^*} \bigg)^{\frac{2}{2^*}} \leq Ck\|f\|_{L^1} .$$ Set $A_{n,k} = \{ |u_{n}| > k \} . $ From the above estimate, and using that $u_{n}^k  = k$ on $A_{n,k}$, we obtain  $$(3) \hspace{1 cm} |A_{n,k}| \leq \big(\frac{\|f\|_{L^1}}{k}\big)^{\frac{d}{d-2}}.$$ Now fix $\lambda > 0$. Observe that $$ \{|\nabla u_n | > \lambda \} \subset A_{n,k} \cup \{ |\nabla u_{n}| > \lambda \cap |u_{n}| < k\}.$$ However using Chebyshev and (2), we get  $$(4) \hspace{1 cm} |\{ |\nabla u_{n}| > \lambda \cap |u_{n}| < k\} | \leq |\{ |\nabla u_{n}^k | > \lambda \}| \leq \frac{1}{\lambda ^2}\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u_{n}^k|^2 \leq \frac{k\|f\|_{L^1}}{\lambda ^2} .$$ In total, using (3) and (4) we get the following upper bound : $$(5) \hspace{1 cm} | \{|\nabla u_n | > \lambda \} | \leq |A_{n,k}| + \frac{k \|f\|_{L^1}}{\lambda ^2}  \leq  \big(\frac{\|f\|_{L^1}}{k}\big)^{\frac{d}{d-2}} + \frac{k \|f\|_{L^1}}{\lambda ^2} .$$ Now we pick $k$ to make the right hand side as small as possible, we choose $$ k = \lambda ^{\frac{d-2}{d-1}} \|f\|_{L^1}^{\frac{1}{d-1}}.$$ This gives $$(6) \hspace{1 cm} | \{|\nabla u_n | > \lambda \} | \leq C\big(\frac{\|f\|_{L^1}}{\lambda}\big)^{\frac{d}{d-1}}.$$ Fix $1\leq q < \frac{d}{d-1},$ and $t > 0.$ Then using the Layer-Cake formula and (6) we get
\begin{equation*} 
\begin{split}\| \nabla u_{n}\|_{q}^{q} &\leq \int_{\{|\nabla u_{n}| > t\}}|\nabla u_{n}|^q + \int_{\{|\nabla u_{n}| \leq  t\}} |\nabla u_{n}|^q  \leq  \int_{\{|\nabla u_{n}| > t\}}|\nabla u_{n}|^q  + t^q|\Omega| 
\\
&\leq 2t^q|\Omega| + q\int_{t}^{\infty}\lambda^{q-1}|\{|\nabla u_{n} > \lambda \}|d\lambda \leq 2t^q|\Omega|^q + Cq\int_{t}^{\infty}\lambda^{q-1}\|f\|_{L^1}\lambda^{\frac{-d}{d-1}}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Evaluating this latter integral, we get $$  (7) \hspace{1 cm}  \| \nabla u_{n}\|_{q}^{q} \leq 2t^q + C \frac{q\|f\|_{L^1}^{\frac{d}{d-1}}}{\frac{d}{d-1}-q}\frac{1}{t^{ \frac{d}{d-1} -q}}  .$$ Choosing $ t = \|f\|_{L^1},$ we arrive at $$(8) \hspace{1 cm}  \| \nabla u_{n}\|_{q} \leq C(q,d)\|f\|_{L^1}.$$
Thus, $ u_{n} $ is a bounded sequence in $ W_{0}^{1,q} ,$ so by Rellich-Kondrachev up to a subsequence, we have $ u_{n} \to u'$ in $L^q$. Moreover, $ \nabla u_{n}$ are bounded in $L^q$, so up to a subsequence $ \nabla u_{n} \rightharpoonup v'$ in the weak $L^q$ topology. It is easy to see that $v'$ must be the weak derivative of $u'$. Note that $ u'$ is in $W^{1,q}$, and $u'$ is the weak limit of the $u_{n}$ in the weak $W^{1,q}$ topology. But $W_{0}^{1,q}$ is a strongly closed and convex subset of $W^{1,q}$, so it follows that $u' \in W_{0}^{1,q} .$ But now note that for all $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\Omega) $ $$ \int_{\Omega} f\varphi = \lim \int_{\Omega}f_{n}\varphi = \lim \int_{\Omega} \langle \nabla \varphi , \; \nabla u_{n} \rangle = \int_{\Omega} \langle \nabla \varphi , \; \nabla u' \rangle , $$ so $u'$  solves the same Dirichlet problem as $u$. By a result of Lions and Dautray, since $\partial \Omega \in C^{1,1} $, we have $u = u'.$ But then by (8) and the fact that $ \nabla u_{n} \rightharpoonup \nabla u $, $ \| \nabla u\|_{q} \leq \liminf \| \nabla u_{n}\|_{q} \leq C \|f\|_{L^1} .$ By Poincare, we have the desired estimate $$ \|u\|_{W_{0}^{1,q}} \leq C \|f\|_{L^1} $$